# Distribute objects in a straight line aligned to normal with geo nodes [Blender 3.0]

Tags: modeling, node-editor, geometry-nodes

How would I generate points in a straight line in a given direction, then align or snap or distribute those points along the normal of an object, and then use those points to distribute a second object. The farthest I got was to generate a mesh line, distribute that with a vertex group from the bottom, and then use an instance on points to distribute my second object. The issue is that I can't translate each of the the points from the mesh line to snap to the normal of the object I'm distributing on.

I understand that I can edit the mesh itself to create a bunch of vertices in a line, add them to a vertex group and use that as the selection input for an "Instance on Points" node. I want to recreate something similar without adding a ton of geometry, and that could ideally be used on different object.

I know this question is kinda confusing but I think the pictures will clarify.

[image]
What I'm trying to accomplish, this was done by adding vertices to the actual mesh

[image]
What I've managed with geo nodes

[image]
My best efforts node setup

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep it simple, just create a vertex group, convert it to a curve, and instantiate your objects along that curve.

Additionally, as seen here in this example, you can transfer the normals of the original faces/points and apply them as rotation when instantiating.

[image]

Note that the node `Named Attribute` is only available from **Blender 3.2**. If you use a lower version, then you would have to get the vertex group in via a *Group Input*!

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>